# SQL: Replace two values in multiple rows in a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with values '< 500' and '> 500' in several hundred rows. Those are the only two figures. Now, I want to replace all '< 500' with 'xx' and all '> 500' with 'yy'.

Is there any way to replace both the values in a single SQL query rather than using two separate update queries as below:

```
UPDATE [table] SET [column] = 'xx' WHERE [column] = '< 500';
UPDATE [table] SET [column] = 'yy' WHERE [column] = '> 500';
```

I tried using Case for this, but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Your syntax suggests SQL Server so I removed the oracle tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use a `case` statement:

```
UPDATE [table]
    SET [column] = (CASE WHEN [column] = '< 500' THEN 'xx' ELSE 'yy' END)
    WHERE [column] IN ('< 500', '> 500');
```

Comment: You type faster than me @Gordon :)